# Using PHP in simple WordPress Simple Paypal Shopping Cart

Tags: php, wordpress

I am ignorant in the field of wordpress so if this question is stupid please forgive me. I am building an instant JavaScript calculator that will calculate your cost. Then if you click a button it will redirect to a page with Simple Paypal Shopping Cart. I want the fields of the simple Paypal shopping cart form to be automatically be filled by the information from the calculator. I want to use PHP to do so. Can you please tell how.

Answer (score 1):

I think you really need to have a go at it first and then pose a question, asking for someone to do it for you isn't really the way forward.  however here is a link found in a 5 second google search:

http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-based-shopping-carts/